# Initializing instance object in designated initializer?

Tags: objective-c, object, inheritance, designated-initializer

I have a Rectangle class which has properties width and height. It also has an instance property/object called *origin* (-(XYPoint *) origin ). Below is the code for my designated initializer in which I pass the XYPoint object as an argument. Is there a way (or is it okay) if I take the properties of the XYPoint class as arguments in this method and then initialize the XYPoint object as well as allocate memory for it inside the method? Otherwise I have to create an XYPoint object in my main program and pass it as an argument which is a lot more code to type.

```
-(id) initWithWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h andOrigin:(XYPoint *)o
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setWidth: w andHeight: h];
        self.origin = o;
    }
    return self;
}
```

P.S.- I am new to programming and Objective C so pardon me if I have stated something technically wrong in my question. Thanks!

Comment: The XYPoint class has an instance method                                    setX:(int) x andY: (int) y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally--I try to avoid initializers that take parameters. I think it leads to writing lots more code and inflexibility. I use designated initializers for just 2 things:

- initializing an object with properties that must not be changed after the object is initialized
- initializing an object with properties that are absolutely needed to construct it and cannot be specified later

In general, for Rectangle class, I'd make the use like this:

```
Rectangle * r = [ [ Rectangle alloc ] init ] ;
r.x = x ;
r.y = y ;
r.origin = o ;

// use r
```

and not use the designated initializer pattern at all except for the conditions outlined above. (For example, creating immutable Rectangle instances)

Finally, there's probably no need to create a Rectangle class--just use CGRect/NSRect primitive structures.

Comment: That means that every time you create a `Rectangle`, you need to repeat the code that would have been in the initializer. Instead of one line, you have four. How would having a `-initWithSize:origin:` lead to "writing lots more code"? Seems like it'd lead to writing less overall.

Comment: To me, code like my example is very straightforward. Always using plain `init` when possible avoids the additional complexity and inflexibility of designated initializers. I.e. let's decide `Rectangle` should have a backgroundColor property... Do I add `initWithSize:origin:backgroundColor:`? Or does the initializer just cover `origin` and `size` with `backgroundColor` set later? Or do I have 3 initializers for the different permutations? etc etc. Using `init` avoids all these questions.

Comment: To me, designated initializers are special cases of the general rule "`init` your objects". Special cases = complexity.